# GitHub Coptilot does not work in NeoVim when editing Python

Tags: python, archlinux, neovim, github-copilot

I have Arch Linux and so the latest NeoVim release is installed (0.7.0 at this moment). About a month I started using GitHub Copilot and it worked well in *Bash, SH, JS* and others. Yesterday I wanted to rewrite some program in Python but Copilot didn't work. Tried it in different files and languages - works everywhere but not Python! `:Copilot status` shows *"Copilot: Enabled and online"*, but gives no suggestions. `:Copilot panel` shows *"Synthesizing 0/10 solutions (Duplicates hidden)"*. `:Copilot log` contains nothing. I remember that some time ago it worked as expected but now it does not. I don't have any ideas why is that happening. As an Arch user I reject VisualStudio Code and other IDEs and prefer working in terminal. Anything that may help?

Edit: just discovered that opening a file without `.py` and printing `#!/usr/bin/env python3` works for Copilot, but in this case there's no syntax highlight. Reopening with `:edit` adds colors but breaks Copilot

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Go. I am however using a new M1 machine. Although the exact same .vimrc :Copilot status says all is ok. log contains nothing

Comment: @RichardVartanMelkonian I've just tested, the same thing. Strange!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just solved it on my machine. I used nvm to set my NodeJS back to v16.13.0. reloaded neovim. Copilot now working as expected.

Copilot was not working on NodeJS v18.0.0.

What's annoying is tim-pope doesn't have the issues section active on the repo. So I'm sure others will run into this. Let me know if this solves it for you.

Comment: When I downgraded to one of the latest 17 version Copilot showed just "Error". Downgrading to older breaks Node because it can't find libcui18n.so.70 - I have .71 now

Comment: Figured it out, 17.9.0 is the right choice. Thank you!

Comment: I can confirm the same issue. It doesn't want to work with 18.

Comment: I've recently switch to lua and use this lua plugin to run copliot. No issues found on multiple versions of node https://github.com/zbirenbaum/copilot.lua